# Why does this allocation of client static IP in OpenVPN fail?

Tags: ip, subnet, openvpn

I am running an OpenVPN server, and I want to assign a specific client a static IP.

This is my server.conf. I *think* this configures the pool of virtual IPs to span from 10.5.24.209 to 10.5.24.223.

```
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.5.24.208 255.255.255.240
#This netmask should span IPs .208-.223.
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 168.xx.xx.xx"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
client-to-client
client-config-dir ccd
```

This is the contents of `/etc/openvpn/ccd/W7LocalVM`, where W7LocalVM is the Common Name of my client. I don't quite understand what this directive does, but I think the first IP should be the desired static IP of my client, and the second IP should be the IP of my server.

```
ifconfig-push 10.5.24.210 10.5.24.209
```

However, when I try to connect my client with this server configuration, I get the following error:

```
Mon Aug 07 14:07:34 2017 Set TAP-Windows TUN subnet mode network/local/netmask = 10.5.24.208/10.5.24.210/10.5.24.209 [SUCCEEDED]
Mon Aug 07 14:07:34 2017 MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
Mon Aug 07 14:07:34 2017 ERROR: --ip-win32 dynamic [offset] : offset is outside of --ifconfig subnet
Mon Aug 07 14:07:34 2017 Exiting due to fatal error
```

I thought the IP 10.5.24.210 would be within the subnet defined on the server side, and I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Could anyone help me out on this?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on Server Fault instead, could get more helpful of feedback since that site is dedicated to server administration issues.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Didn't know about that community. Should I repost, or is there some feature that lets me migrate the post?

Comment: You can flag for moderator intervention and ask them to migrate. (For a few sites, like Super User, the community can vote to migrate, but migration to that site has to be done by moderators).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is created because openvpn is trying to parse your ifconfig options as an ip followed by an subnet mask.

According to the man page:

> **--topology mode**
>
> ...
>
> subnet -- Use a subnet rather than a point-to-point topology by
> configuring the tun interface with a local IP address and subnet mask,
> similar to the topology used in --dev tap and ethernet bridging mode.
> This mode allocates a single IP address per connecting client and
> works on Windows as well. Only available when server and clients are
> OpenVPN 2.1 or higher, or OpenVPN 2.0.x which has been manually
> patched with the --topology directive code. When used on Windows,
> requires version 8.2 or higher of the TAP-Win32 driver. When used on
> *nix, requires that the tun driver supports an ifconfig(8) command which sets a subnet instead of a remote endpoint IP address.
>
> This option exists in OpenVPN 2.1 or higher.
>
> **Note: Using --topology subnet changes the interpretation of the
> arguments of --ifconfig to mean "address netmask", no longer "local
> remote".**
>
> **--ifconfig l rn**
>
> Set TUN/TAP adapter parameters. l is the IP address of the local VPN endpoint. For TUN devices in point-to-point mode, rn is
> the IP address of the remote VPN endpoint. For TAP devices, **or TUN
> devices used with --topology subnet**, **rn is the subnet mask of the
> virtual network segment which is being created or connected to**. For
> TUN devices, which facilitate virtual point-to-point IP connections
> (when used in --topology net30 or p2p mode), the proper usage of
> --ifconfig is to use two private IP addresses which are not a member of any existing subnet which is in use. The IP addresses may be
> consecutive and should have their order reversed on the remote peer.
> After the VPN is established, by pinging rn, you will be pinging
> across the VPN.
>
> For TAP devices, which provide the....

Inside you server code, you set your topology to `subnet`, and then push it to the client using the `server` statement.

According to the above documentation, instead of pushing your ifconfig using "local", "remote" address, you need to add the following to "/etc/openvpn/ccd/W7LocalVM":

```
ifconfig-push 10.5.24.210 255.255.255.252
push route 10.5.24.210 255.255.255.252
# ifconfig 10.5.24.209 255.255.255.252
```

The last line is probably not needed, but is left as an example what ifconfig-push "should" do on the server side to make the connection work.

Comment: I wrote a comment here asking why you suggested allocating four IPs per client, but I was industrious enough to find the answer for that in the FAQ. Thank you for solving the riddle!

Comment: @Magnus Which FAQ are you referring to? This one? https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/273-qifconfig-poolq-option-use-a-30-subnet-4-private-ip-addresses-per-client-when-used-in-tun-mode? Or another one?

Comment: It's been a while @Akito, and I've forgotten which FAQ it was. I should have had the foresight to link it for future readers. However, I remember that each of the four IPs was required by OpenVPN in some fashion.

Comment: @Magnus I see. It's alright. That already helps. Thank you!